# jQuery event when clicked AND link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The title is a bit confusing but here's what I want to do -> There's a picture. When you click on it, a lightbox pops up (I already have that event). However, if you right click it and open in a new tab, I want a page to appear. Instagram has something similar to what I'm looking for. `<a href="">` doesn't work - it executes both (launches the lightbox and redirects). How do I do that? Is there a way to cancel the `href`? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Here's a visual: http://jsfiddle.net/9VFGS/. In that case, I only want the `alert()` to be invoked when I click on it, but when I open it in a new tab, I want it to navigate to google.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `event.preventDefault()` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)) in the event handler for triggering your lightbox will prevent the link from executing and changing your window location. Right-click context actions should still work, though, because they don't trigger `click` events.

```
$( '#my-link' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // do my lightbox stuff here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set `href="..."` to `href="#"`.

Comment: Hm, I think you didn't understand what I was saying. I still want the link to be there so that when you open it in a new tab I get to that page, but a jQuery event is invoked when you just click on it.